# How to view Parent-Child Process, Zombie Process, Daemon Process on a Unix or Linux environment?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, zsh

To view Parent-Child Process:

> ps -f

To view Zombie Process:

> ps aux
> and look for processes with Z in STAT column

To view Daemon Process:

> ps -ef | grep ?

Answer (score -1):

To view Parent-Child Process:  ps -f

To view Zombie Process:  ps aux
then look for processes with Z in STAT column

To view Daemon Process:  ps -ef | grep ?